# Why isn't there a User Interface Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Back Story:

I've constantly seen UI questions rejected on the User Experience Stack Exchange and told to go to the Graphic Design Stack, which I'd be inclined to argue is different and you rarely see UI questions on there.

UI is interlinked with UX so I dont know why the questions get rejected so much, but it is also its own profession too.

So with this frustration, I tried to set one up on here but it got shut down due to it being a 'duplicate of the User Experience Stack Exchange'. So you can see my conundrum and frustration. My example questions probably weren't the best but they where up for discussion and improvements.

This sounds like im a bit bitter! I'm honestly not, im just trying to solve a problem I have come across as a UI Designer wanting to put my questions out there.

You can see the original proposal here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118967/user-interface

Comment: The people who suggested you ask here instead of Area51 didn't mean ask this question here. UX Meta has no control over what new proposals are accepted or rejected. They meant "Ask on Meta about why your questions were being closed as off topic". Can you give links to questions that were closed as off topic on UX that you think should be on topic?

Comment: UI is more than just graphical user interface. In 2019 UI is also speech, physical controls, augmented reality or anything else that is computer enabled. These all implement User Experience and it seems silly that they wouldn’t be discussed right here in User Experience Stack Exchange. I think of UX.SE as the place I go to ask about how to solve problems about how people interact with products, services and experiences. Efficient answers often involve implementation details.

Comment: Put more succinctly, it makes sense to me you’d ask UI questions here on UX.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is an interesting question to consider but I think because there is less of an 'implementation' focus on this site so anything to do with the UI goes to Graphics StackExchange and anything to do with coding goes to StackOverflow or Programming StackExchange. It feels like the only part of UX that we cover is the research aspects of the process, when I suppose we should be looking at questions that deal with the entire process involved.

I have looked at the Questions that you have posted, but this only forms part of the analysis because we don't know what kind of questions were rejected/closed. I too have lots of questions closed (and I have also deleted some myself) and had other questions referred/moved to other sites (and sometimes they also get moved or closed :p).

My feeling is that the current focus is on the UX of the UI (i.e. why we might do something and not how we do something) rather than pure UI (i.e. how do we design/implement this thing), so you may find that the questions that you have asked fit more into the 'interaction design' tag instead of the 'gui-design' related tags.

Comment: That last paragraph does hit the nail on the head. I agree too that we should be looking at the entire process involved, which UI does fall into. I feel there seems to be a grey area around how UI questions should be asked because the line between feedback and "how should/should i do this" type questions is quite fine for UI.